# Отображение свойства текущего элемента коллекции в ListBox XAML/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Не отображается свойство `name` текущего элемента из коллекции `EdgeCollection`, которое в классе, привязанном к `DataContex`.
Если убрать блок `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>`, то просто применяется `ToString` к элементу коллекции и выводится полное имя типа. Перегрузка `ToString` не вариант.

```
<ListBox Margin="5"
         ItemsSource="{Binding EdgeCollection}"
         SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Скриншоты: [xaml_code](http://www.fotolink.su/v.php?id=da10ca6747ff2317eced85b94c6ca16f), 
[EditorViewModel_code](http://www.fotolink.su/v.php?id=4160dd5966a3d5baf402dfb467a903f9), [NodeInfo](https://vfl.ru/fotos/4dbc576a17954807.html).

Comment: не могли бы вы привести упрощённую версию вашего класса. Имя переменной с маленькой буквы, так обычно обозначают приватные и локальные переменные. вы уверены, что `name` это вообще открытое свойство?

Comment: для привязки необходимо использовать именно публичные свойства. Например: `public string Name {get; set;}`

Comment: Да, "name" это публичное свойство структуры с геттером. К сожалению, данный тип не мой, а из библиотеки.

Comment: Есть класс EditorViewModel, который привязан к DataContex соответствующего EditorView в конструкторе code behind. У этого класса есть коллекция структур NodeInfo, у которых есть публичное свойство "name" с геттером, но без сеттера.

Comment: вопрос возможно глупый, то `name` это точно строка?

Comment: Да, это строка)

Comment: Ээ.. залейте файлы лучше туда, где код можно будет посмотреть. Тот же pasterbin.com

Comment: Скринов хватает? Или всё таки залить?

Comment: Ещё есть DataContext = new EditorViewModel(); в code behind editor.xaml

Comment: Покажите структуру класса, который пытаетесь привязать, а не xaml разметку

Comment: Привязывается экземпляр класса EditorViewModel, скриншот которого выложен выше.

Comment: можно узнать почемувы просто не используете свойство `DisplayMemberPath`? то есть у вас будет `DisplayMemberPath="name"`

Comment: @Mr. Modest В каком классе?

Comment: вы показали как выглядит `NodeInfo`, а не `EdgeInfo`, к которому вы привязываетесь

Comment: мы можем продолжить обсуждение в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f) ?, мне кажется так мы быстрее найдем проблему

Comment: Упс, случайно NodeInfo скинул. Сейчас выложу EdgeInfo, хотя принципиально они не отличаются.

Comment: Да, конечно, давайте в чате.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я обращался к свойству `name` структуры `EdgeInfo`, которое у неё не существует, но существует у структуры `NodeInfo`, из-за этого произошла путаница.